# Swift Cannot invoke initializer for type 'WebSocket' with an argument list of type '(url: URL)

Tags: ios, swift, starscream

I have following code in swift for web-socket communication, but when I build the  code I am getting error.

**Code:**

```
import Foundation
import Starscream

class StarscreamWebSocket: WebSocketProvider {

    var delegate: WebSocketProviderDelegate?
    private let socket: WebSocket
    
    init(url: URL) {
        self.socket = WebSocket(url: url)
        self.socket.delegate = self
    }
    
    func connect() {
        self.socket.connect()
    }
    
    func send(data: Data) {
        self.socket.write(data: data)
    }
}
```

**Error:**

`Cannot invoke initializer for type 'WebSocket' with an argument list of type '(url: URL)'`

What could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This framework's `WebSocket` class doesn't have an initializer that takes a single `URL` parameter. It has two initializers:

```
public init(request: URLRequest, engine: Engine)
public convenience init(request: URLRequest, certPinner: CertificatePinning? = FoundationSecurity(), compressionHandler: CompressionHandler? = nil, useCustomEngine: Bool = true)
```

You seem to want to use the second one. Just create a `URLRequest` with your `URL`

```
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
self.socket = WebSocket(request: request )
```

Comment: Actually I was using the code from here https://github.com/stasel/WebRTC-iOS/blob/master/WebRTC-Demo-App/Sources/Services/WebSocketProvider/StarscreamProvider.swift

Comment: The author probably wrote a small extension for `WebSocket` and added an initialier that takes a `URL` for convenience.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I am new to swift, probably I am missing something in my code.

Comment: But here in these example only one argument passed https://scorocode.github.io/scorocode-docs-en/SWIFT/WebSocket/   https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream

Comment: This link is outdated. When you look at the library's repository, you can see that it used to have an initializer with a `URL` parameter on the branch `swift4` but it has since been removed. Example in library's `README.md` uses `URLRequest`, not `URL`